# If $ a+b+c=4 ; a^2=b^2+c=6 ; a^3+b^3+c^3=8 $ Then find the value of $a^4+b^4+c^4$

Tags: quadratics, systems-of-equations

If

1. $a+b+c=4$
2. $ a^2=b^2+c=6$ (this is not symmetric equation)
3. $a^3+b^3+c^3=8$

Then find the value of $a^4+b^4+c^4$

Comment: Is `2)` meant to be `a^2+b^2+c=6`, is it meant to be `a^2+b^2+c^2=6` or something else?

Comment: Did you mean the first $=$ sign in the second line?  or should it be $+$?

Comment: na its = ..the question is correct

Comment: Are the numbers supposed to be real?

Comment: If that's really the equation, then $a=\pm \sqrt{6}$.

Comment: If the second equation really is two equations, then the (overdetermined) system of four equations has (hardly a surprise) no solutions (says Mathematica).

Comment: we have 3 equations of b and c and two variables.But its is not easy to solve.

Comment: $a^2=b^2+c=6$ is two equations, @mathslover. That is why people keep asking whether that equation is what you meant. The total of equations here is $4$.

Comment: The system

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a+b+c=4 \\ 
a^{2}=b^{2}+c \\ 
a^{2}=6 \\ 
a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}=8
\end{array}
\right. $$

has no solutions.

Comment: If the second equation was $a^2+b^2+c^2=6$, this would be a very common type of problem involving symmetric polynomials.

Comment: Care to tell us more about the origin of this problem. Given that there are no solutions we need to start debugging!